# Fill a figure and remove noise - OpenCV Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So guys I'll explain quickly.
I have a fixed camera and I took a photo thus obtaining the "background".
Then my friend stood in front of the camera and I took another photo.

I want to get an image where **there is only my friend** in the foreground and where it is necessary to **delete the background**.
I have tried many methods (`absdiff()`, tensorflow + bodypix and more) but the only method that is giving me good results is using `SubtractorKNN`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

backgroundSubtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(detectShadows=True)

# apply the algorithm for background images using learning rate > 0
for i in range(1, 16):
   bgImageFile = "background.jpg"
   print ("Opening background", bgImageFile)
   bg = cv2.imread(bgImageFile)
   backgroundSubtractor.apply(bg, learningRate=0.9)

# apply the algorithm for detection image using learning rate 0
stillFrame = cv2.imread("background-with-friend.jpg")
fgmask = backgroundSubtractor.apply(stillFrame, learningRate=0.9)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
morphology_img = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel,iterations=1)
nuovo = morphology_img

#'nuovo.jpg' is nuovo
ok= cv2.imread('nuovo.jpg')
giona = cv2.cvtColor(ok, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,range = cv2.threshold(giona,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("nuovo kernel", cv2.resize(nuovo, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
cv2.imshow("range", cv2.resize(range, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5))
```

[image]

**THE QUESTION IS**:
there is a way to reconstruct the outline (e.g. left leg, face, arms), fill inside (then eliminate the black spots) and eliminate the white dots in the background (I have already used cv2.morphologyEx but use a kernel bigger would have further ruined the outline of the person).
Is possible ?

**If I can get the figure of the person then I can remove the background from the original image.**

---

**EDIT**
I used `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorKNN`, then `cv2.morphologyEx`and finally `cv2.threshold(img,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`to delete shadows

Comment: To do this well, you need an AI/Deep Learning solution. See http://remove.bg for example

Comment: @fmw42 wow that website like example is incredible! But i’m trying to create something from zero. Free... for me and all Automatic :( :(

Comment: Can you post the original, unprocessed image?